# Promisify a node function that loops AWS lamda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda, bluebird

I want to create a promise node function that loop the AWS lambda function but I could not see how could it be possible with bluebird promise.
Do you have any example of that implementation?

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
 const lambdaInvokeAsync = Promise.promisify(lambda.invoke, {context: 
 lambda});
 for(var page = 1; page <= totalPages; page++){

  var params = {
    FunctionName: MOCK_API_FUNCTION /* required */,
    Payload: '{"page":'+page+', "limit": '+limit+', "retrievalDate":'
              +retrievalDate+ '}';
  };

   return lambdaInvokeAsync(params)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Successfully retrieve data');
      var dataPerPage = JSON.parse(result.Payload).data;
      dataArr.push(dataPerPage); 

      return dataArr;
    });

}
```

Comment: why you put the `return` befor `lambdaInvokeAsync(params)...`? it exists the for-loop

Comment: Your problem is not the promisification but rather that you `return` from inside the loop. That can't work, not even without any promises.

Answer (score 0):

`aws-sdk` supports promises since v2.3.0.

You can use `lambda.invoke(params).promise()` to return a promise.

With that, your code becomes...

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

const invokes = [];

for (let page = 1; page <= totalPages; page++) {
  const request = lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: MOCK_API_FUNCTION /* required */ ,
    Payload: '{"page":' + page + ', "limit": ' + limit + ', "retrievalDate":' +
      retrievalDate + '}';
    }).promise();

  invokes.push(request);
}

const dataArr = Promise.all(invokes)
  .map(result => JSON.parse(result.Payload).data)
```